# angular use [innerHTML] with *ngFor variable reference

Tags: angular, angular5, innerhtml, angular-components, angular-template

I am building my own grid component `app-grid` in which I pass columns as an array of objects, I am trying to add the ability to send cell template as HTML, since some cells have more complex code than just displaying the value.

I was able to use `innerHtml` like this:

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns">
    <span *ngIf="col.cellTemplate" [innerHTML]="col.cellTemplate"></span> 
    <span *ngIf="!col.cellTemplate"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
</td>
```

**** my issue is that `[innerHTML]` does not compile.

meaning I am unable to use the reference of the cell data value in  the cellTemplate that I set in columns array when I use this grid in another component, how can I send a custom cellTemplate and at the same time be able to use the variable of `{{rowData[col.field]}}` from the grid component *ngFor ?

```
<app-grid columns="columns" data="data"></app-grid>
```

and the columns array as :

```
columns = [
    { 
        field: 'test',
        cellTemplate: '<h3 [routerLink]="[ \'/\', rowData[col.field], 'some_url']">{{rowData[col.field]}}</h3>'
    },
    { 
        ..... 
    },

    { 
        ..... 
    }
];
```

Comment: Hey, Can you know me which kind of data is getting in a rowData object and how you set in the column array? innerHTML is working fine may be an issue in the celltemplate.

Comment: hi @VishalMaru, data is being passed as an array of objects , my challenge is accessing another component's ngFor, is that working fine for you? to pass the html with variables that are defined in the component you're passing to?  actually I am using the primeng data table but just trying to add custom cell templating https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Comment: Hey please try this.   this.columns = [
    {
   fields: 'test',
   cellTemplate: '<h3 [routerLink]="[ \'/\', '+rowData[col.field]+', '+some_url+']">'+rowData[col.field]+'</h3>'
    }
    ]

Comment: @VishalMaru, see that is the issue I am trying to explain, it is that rowData is not defined in the component , plus I want to set the cellTemplate through in the columns, I don't want to loop through all data in my component that is using the grid. your suggestion will result to error because using rowData as variable will lead to undefined

Comment: try to use `div` instead of `span` tag